# how to resolve eclipse update site dependency

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I build up update site project form eclipse,I do not know how to resolve plug-in dependency in `feature.xml`,I am setting "Included Features" and "Dependencies",but at the end when add locations for target definition throw "`package javax.crypto 0.0.0`";that jar is jre lib ....how to resolve?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq8wm.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select the Java Runtime Environment on the 3rd tab called "Environment" e.g. to Execution Environment: "JavaSE-1.8"
Makes sure to save and add your repo afterwards. Then it the target should also include the packages from the JRE.